# Is there any easy way to fit probability mass function to a given dataset?

Tags: python, statistics, probability, data-fitting

Assume we have a list of numbers (samples)

> data = [0,0,1,2,3]

I would like to fit a probability mass function for this dataset, in such a way that if I do something like

> pmf.fit(data)

and by executing something like

> pmf.eval(0)

I get

> 0.2

as return

and

by executing

> pmf.eval(-1)

I get

> 0

as return.

Note that I am working with a discrete random variable here, so I am not fitting a pdf...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out myself

> random_array = [0,0,1,2,3]

> unique, counts = np.unique(random_array, return_counts=True)

> random_variable = sp.stats.rv_discrete(a = 0, b = np.inf, values = (unique, counts/np.sum(counts)))